# ppm format that have magic code P3

Tags: c

how i can read ppm image that have  magic code P3. in c language?
this code reading ppm image that have  magic code P3 but there a problem with loading method,this code enters into in infinite loop when reading the value of pixles?

```
    /* This is for reading and Writing images file in PPM
    Also example of making Negative images

    - Use this file as an example of reading (loading) and writing (storing) images files.

    - This program loads an PPM image and store a new image that is the negative of the      original image.


    */
    typedef struct pdata {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    } pdata;
    typedef struct ppm {
    int w;
    int h;
    int max;
    pdata *pData;
    } ppm;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define kernelW 3
//#define kernelH 3
//#define imageW 403
//#define imageH 332
char filename[256];

/*
   This LoadPGM function is an updated version that will deal with
   comments in file headers and do at least some basic checking if the
   file can be opened or is the correct format. It does assume the file
   is actually a valid length once the header has been read.

   You are of course free to use your own file reading functions.
*/

void LoadPGM( char* filename, ppm* pPgm ) {
  FILE* ifp;
  int word;
  int nRead = 0;
  char readChars[256];

  //open the file, check if successful
  ifp = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if (!ifp) {
    printf("Error: Unable to open file %s.\n\n", filename);
    exit(1);
  }

  //read headers from file
  printf ("Reading PPM file: %s...\n", filename);
  fscanf (ifp, "%s", readChars);

  if (strcmp(readChars, "P3") == 0) {
    //valid file type
    //get a word from the file
    fscanf (ifp, "%s", readChars);
    while (readChars[0] == '#') {
      //if a comment, get the rest of the line and a new word
      fgets (readChars, 255, ifp);
      fscanf (ifp, "%s", readChars);
    }

    //ok, comments are gone
    //get width, height, color depth
    sscanf (readChars, "%d", &pPgm->w);
    fscanf (ifp, "%d", &pPgm->h);
    fscanf (ifp, "%d", &pPgm->max);

    // allocate some memory, note that on the HandyBoard you want to
    // use constant memory and NOT use calloc/malloc
      pPgm = (ppm *)malloc(sizeof(ppm));
     pPgm->pData = (pdata*)malloc(pPgm->w *pPgm->h * sizeof(pPgm->pData));
 fscanf(ifp, "%d" ,&word);
      pPgm->pData[0].red = word;
      printf (" %d \n", word);
    for (nRead = 0; nRead < pPgm->w * pPgm->h; nRead++) {
      fscanf(ifp, "%d" ,&word);
      // printf (" %d \n",word);
      pPgm->pData[nRead].red = word;
      fscanf(ifp, "%d" ,&word);
      pPgm->pData[nRead].green = word;
      fscanf(ifp, "%d" ,&word);
      pPgm->pData[nRead].blue = word;

    }

    printf ("Loaded PPM. Size: %dx%d, Greyscale: %d \n",
        pPgm->w, pPgm->h, pPgm->max + 1);
  }
  else {
    printf ("Error: Read file type %s. Format unsupported.\n\n", readChars);
    exit(1);
  }
  fclose(ifp);
}

/* Simply saves the PGM file to a file whose name is in filename */

void WritePGM( char* filename, ppm* pPgm ) {
  FILE* ofp;
  int w, h, max;
  int nWrite = 0;
  int i,j;


  strcat(filename, ".out.ppm");
  ofp = fopen(filename, "w");
  if (!ofp) {
    printf("Error: Unable to open file %s.\n\n", filename);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf ("Writing ouput PPM: %s\n\n", filename);


  //write the header
  fprintf( ofp, "P3\n" );
  fprintf( ofp, "%d %d\n", pPgm->w, pPgm->h );
 //  printf("Done. Have a nice day...\n\n");
  fprintf( ofp, "%d\n", pPgm->max );


  //write the image data
  for (i = 0; i < pPgm->h;i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < pPgm->w; j++)
      fprintf(ofp,"%d ",*(pPgm->pData + i * pPgm->w + j));
    fprintf(ofp,"\n");
  }
  fclose(ofp);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  ppm* image, *r1,*r2;
 // char filename[256];
  int val;
  int errchk;
  char f1[256];

  //check if a filename was given, if not, ask for one
  if (argc > 1) {
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
  }
  else {
    printf ("Enter filename: ");
    scanf ("%s", filename);
  }

  //allocate memory for the pgm struct
  image = (ppm *) malloc (sizeof(ppm));




  //read the file
  LoadPGM(filename, image);
 int h,w;

w=image->w;
h=image->h;

int* pBuff1;
int* pBuff2;

   int size;
   int sum=0;




 WritePGM(filename, image);




//  end of the program
}
```

Comment: You are printing out intermediate values, which is a good debug procedure (well, apart from using an actual debugger). Which loop is the infinite one?

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
malloc(pPgm->w *pPgm->h * sizeof(pPgm->pData))
```

allocates the wrong size. It allocates `sizeof(pointer)` while you need it `sizeof(pdata)`, your own RGB struct.

Typically, one only needs RGB as 3 unsigned char, and had you used that the error would have been invisible, since pointers are usually 4 bytes long (and nowadays can even be longer). *But* since you made your values each an int, the structure uses 12 bytes in total. Somewhere after the first third has been read (give or take), your code starts overwriting other stuff in memory and you get toasted.